# What does "Dibs on his wings" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, grammaticality

When I watched "how I met your mother" season 5 ep15, Robin said: "Dibs on his wings" when she saw Barney was on TV, showed his phone number for any girl to call if that woman wanted to sleep with him. What does Robin mean when she said that?

PS: Is there any mistake in my grammar?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-origin-dibs)

> **Calling 'dibs'**
> [...] When someone says that they **have dibs on something**, they claim or
> declare rights to that thing before anyone else

I don't remember the episode exactly but when Robin saw Barney on the T.V, she guessed that Barney was not going to return soon so she claims his (chicken) wings, probably what they're eating at the bar at that moment.